# Trouble understanding the double slit probability measure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, probability

The probability of a particle going into either of two slits is given, classically, by

$$
P=P(\text{slit}_1)+P(\text{slit}_2)=|\psi_1|^2+|\psi_2|^2=1 \tag{1}
$$

This probability must be equal to $1$ as the probability of going through either of two slits is 1.

Likewise, in the quantum scenario, the rules for probability amplitude produce:

$$
P=|\psi_1+\psi_2|^2=|\psi_1|^2+|\psi_2|^2+2|\psi_1||\psi_2|^2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) \tag{2}
$$

Often (such as here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude#In_the_context_of_the_double-slit_experiment) (2) is presented as the quantum version of (1). But I do not understand how this is possible, because (2) does not always sum to unity. Sometimes it's equal to zero. I have drawn P as a function of $\theta_1-\theta_2$ for some dummy values and I get the following:

[image]

For instance at point $\pi/2$, then $P=0$. How can the sum of probability be equal to $0$ and not $1$?

Comment: Classically (for starters) why would the particle have to go through one of the slits?  Are your probabilities meant to be conditional on getting past the barrier?

Comment: You are confusing the probability of going through each slit with the wavefunction/probability density of the position at the screen.

Comment: @WillO yes, they are conditional on passing the first barrier.

Comment: @fqq I agree, but then what is the quantum analog to (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call $P$ which is $|\psi_1+\psi_2|^2$ is a probability *density* function. To get the probability of finding the particle within some range you would need to integrate the density over the correct range to get the probability of finding the particle within that range. There is no issue for $P=0$, that just means you won't find the particle there ever, and it is unlikely to find it within a neighborhood about that point.

The condition that probabilities sum to $1$ here is that $\int P\,\text d\mathbf x=1$.

Comment: So the quantum analog of (1) is actually: $\int |\psi_1+\psi_2| d\mathbf{x}=1$, and not (2)?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay If I understand what you are saying, yes I believe so :)

Comment: How can over integrate $P$ which contains the cosine term between minus and plus infinity? Must one select a finite domain? Are finite domains of integration even allowed for a probability?