# How do I normalize the complex interference of two states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization

Let me define two complex-valued functions as follows:

$$
\psi_1(r_1,\theta_1)=r_1e^{i\theta_1}\\
\psi_2(r_2,\theta_2)=r_2e^{i\theta_2}
$$

By the Born rule I can calculate the probability density, a real-value function, as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
P(r_1,r_2,\theta_1,\theta_2)&=|\psi_1+\psi_2|^2\\
&=|r_1e^{i\theta_1}+r_2e^{i\theta_2}|^2\\
&=(r_1e^{i\theta_1}+r_2e^{i\theta_2})(r_1e^{-i\theta_1}+r_2e^{-i\theta_2})\\
&=r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1r_2e^{i\theta_1-i\theta_2}+r_1r_2e^{i\theta_2-i\theta_1}\\
&=r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos( \theta_1-\theta_2)
\end{align}
$$

---

Now I am trying to understand how to work with this system of probability. But I do not understand the physical intuition behind what we have to create in order to make the normalization constant finite, and let me explain. One option is to restrict the domain to an arbitrary finite value. For instance, I can integrate as follows:

$$
Z=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1P(r_1,r_2,\theta_1,\theta_2)d\theta_1d\theta_2dr_1dr_2
$$

This integral over only part of the domain of the wavefunction will equal a constant. But I feel like this operation is "dirty" in the sense that I am "deleting" or "truncating" a part of the wavefunction I may not be supposed to. I am imagining an experimental setup where photons hit a plate of a certain size. The plate is finite, therefore some photons will miss it and will continue their journey indefinitely in space. So by setting a finite domain of integration, it appears I am creating a probability conditional upon the photon hitting the plate, whilst ignoring photons that miss it --- is this the case?

Another feature I find counter-intuitive is that to perform a purely mathematical operation called normalization, I must somehow introduce a ton of physical baggage. Specifically, I need to create a geometric structure (space or space-time) to place my detector in, which I then use to normalize my probability distribution. Why are probability amplitudes not normalizable without geometry? The requirement appears to be that I must parametrize $\psi_1,\psi_2$ with respect to another variable, say $x$, whose geometry is such that the probability density can be normalized when integrated over its domain. It does then appear to me that $x$ is simply a description of the detector. A variable $x$ integrated between 1 and 2 would then be a representation of a one-meter long detector, etc, and the probability density normalized with respect to it would be conditional of the photon hitting the one-meter long detector? Is this, in fact, the correct interpretation?

Then, with this interpretation, I am of course free to integrate a wavefunction over any domain which yields a finite value, because 1) the system is conditional upon hitting the detector and 2) for any domain I can claim my experimental setup is made from a detector which is exactly the domain.

Comment: related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566198/can-there-be-an-interference-term-in-a-two-state-quantum-system and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566111/trouble-understanding-the-double-slit-probability-measure

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111359/discussion-on-question-by-alexandre-h-tremblay-how-do-i-normalize-the-complex-i).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a conceptual confusion between the polar coordinates of the planar domains of your wavefunctions and the polar form of their complex values. They can both be written in notation using $r$ and $\theta$, but they have nothing to do with each other. The Euclidean plane is not the complex plane.

If you really intend for $r$ and $\theta$ to be the polar coordinates of their domains on an infinite plane, then you have to integrate the radial coordinates from $0$ to infinity, not $1$, unless there is some reason that the wavefunctions are zero for $r>1$, and you have to integrate the angular coordinates from $0$ to $2\pi$, not $1$, unless there is some reason that the wavefunctions are zero for $1<\theta<2\pi$.

But, as written, the complex *value* of your wavefunctions is just equal to $x+iy$ in Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$, and such wavefunctions are not normalizable over an infinite plane because the normalization integral doesn’t converge.

So I conclude that you have misconceived this problem and, as written, it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: But then, how does one write out the probability for a double-slit experiment, for instance as shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude#In_the_context_of_the_double-slit_experiment I was under the impression I had written the same equation.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay That section does not have anything to say about the spatial dependence of the wavefunctions. It is discussing their interference at one unspecified point. The $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are not polar coordinates in some planar *domain* of the wavefunctions. (Besides, the domain is presumably a 3D one.) These angles are the phases of their complex *values* at that point.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay You can write the probability *density* at that point (assuming that both wavefunctions are normalized), but you can’t say anything about the actual probability over any spatial range because you don’t know the spatial dependence.